# Let $L = F(S)$ for $S \subseteq L$. Does there exists a transcendental basis $T \subseteq S$ with $F(S) = F(T)$?

Tags: extension-field, transcendence-theory, transcendence-degree, algebraic-independence

Let $L/F$ be a field extension with $L = F(S)$ for a subset $S \subseteq L$. My first question is:

- Is there a subset $T \subseteq S$ such that $T$ is a transcendental basis?

Now let's say we have $I \subseteq S$ such that $I$ is algebraic independent. My second question is then:

- Is there a subset $T$ with $I \subseteq T \subseteq S$ such that $T$ is a transcendental basis?

Comment: No difficulty if $S$ is countable, just enumerate and check if it is algebraically dependent over the previous. If uncountable then you may need the axiom of choice.

Comment: Thank you! In my case $S$ is finite. So in my case this is sufficient.